# How do I remove a top-level directory from an SVN repository without losing history?

Tags: svn, svnadmin

I have a SVN repository with the following layout:

```
trunk/somedir/a
             /b
             /[et cetera]

branches/branch1/somedir/a
                        /b
                        /[et cetera]

branches/branch2/somedir/a
                        /b
                        /c
```

where there are ~60 branches and about 17000 revisions in the whole repository.  Unfortunately, local convention has been to keep `svn:mergeinfo` information on the `somedir` directories, rather than the root of the branch.  This has created some difficulties when trying to use parsing tools like Fisheye, and migration tools like `git svn` and the hg convertextension.

I can, of course, use `svn move` and reorder everything correctly - but I'd really like to do that over history, so that the conversion tools work more sanely.  Do I have to write a custom tool for this, or is there a way to do this with `svnadmin` and `svndumpfilter`?

Answer (score 0):

svn move is ok with history. But merges between branches will became difficult. (find why moves and renames are problematic in svn).
I have similar problem and I wait until there was only trunk and reorganized repository structure in that moment.
Merge-info (you can copy merge info from somedir to trunk. It is just svn properties.

I havent tried svnadmin tools, if You have succed with it let me now :)

Comment: unfortunately, my repo will never be in a state where just trunk exists; we support multiple releases simultaneously.  Too bad!